# Is there a way to connect LOCALHOST without using ComputerName in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to connect <kbd>LOCALHOST DatabaseEgnine</kbd> without providing the computer name like `MyComputerName\LOCALHOST` ?

(I use SQL Server 2012 - Standard Edition installed)

Comment: You can use `.` or `(local)` as identifier for local default SQL Server instance.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear: is your SQL Server instance default or named? And why exactly do you want to avoid providing the computer name? If you can tell us why you want to do that, someone may have a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

`MyComputerName\LOCALHOST` is [**named instance**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) called `LOCALHOST` on your computer. To connect to it you must either specify the instance name (and have the [SQL Server Browser service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) running) or specify the listening port explicitly (and have the instance [configured to listen to static port](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938), non-default since default is dynamic ports). So any of the below will work:

- `.\LOCALHOST`
- `localhost\LOCALHOST`
- `local\LOCALHOST`
- `127.0.0.1\LOCALHOST`
- `machinename\LOCALHOST`
- `.:<port>`
- `localhost:<port>`
- `127.0.0.1:<port>`
- etc

Is very unlikely you actually wanted to install a named instance called LOCALHOST. You probably didn't read the setup dialogs and misconfigured the instance name. My recommendation would be to install it again, choosing a default instance (ie. unnamed) or a more convenient and less confusing instance name.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.` as servername
e.g.

```
    .\mssqlserver 
    .\sqlexpress
```

Answer (score 1):

For Default Instance:::

(local) or .  (it is a dot)

Named Instance:
(local)\InstanceName  (or) .\InstanceName